# Read an element from the @ViewChild without using nativeElement

Tags: javascript, angular, viewchild

Is there anyway to get the underlying div element on a `@ViewChild`? I have tried to read the following of which none work:

- `ElementRef.prototype.nativeElement` -- returns `ElementRef`
- `HTMLDivElement` -- returns `undefined`
- `ElementRef` -- returns `ElementRef`

I am trying to do this so I can do without having to call `nativeElement` in every call to the `content` property.

Here is what I am doing (replacing the `read` with an item from the list above):

```js
  @ViewChild('overlayContent', { read: ElementRef.prototype.nativeElement })
  content?: HTMLDivElement;
```

```html
<div class="slide-over-content" #overlayContent>
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: It is unclear why you want to do this. What you are trying to do is a very bad idea, You are now coupling your child logic to the parent. Is there a reason why you wont expose a method instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common pattern is to use a setter if one more level of abstraction is needed between an ElementRef and its property.

```
 @ViewChild('overlayContent')
    set aRef(ref: ElementRef) {
      this.myDomElement = ref.nativeElement;
    }
```

Comment: to add on this, you can access the native element by referencing the template variable directly in the template as well
`<div #myElement><p[style.width.px]="myElement.getBoundingClientRect().width">Hello</p></div>`

Comment: Yes. Also, the template variables can be used directly in other DOM elements too.